# How to print a specific column condition using awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have an input file :

```
A 123 name: 1 AAA  
B 123 name: 2 AAA name: 3 BBB  
C 234 name: 1 AAA name: 2 BBB name: 5 CCC
```

If the column is 'name:', I want to print the next and the next column.

This is my awk code:

```
cat input.txt | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i == "name:")print $(i+1),$(i+2)}'
```

But, in this case, all columns are listed in a line like this:

```
1 AAA  
2 AAA  
3 BBB  
1 AAA  
2 BBB  
5 CCC
```

I want the columns to be printed like this:

```
1 AAA  
2 AAA 3 BBB    
1 AAA 2 BBB 5 CCC
```

Comment: Try with: `awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF-3; i++) $i = $(i+3); NF-=3; print}' inputfile | sed -e 's/name: //g'` However, as reading again the question, it seems that there is the possibility that not all the columns have the same format (I understand that may be some lines which don't have 'name:' column), isn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just replace `print` with `printf` to print the value on the same line, and insert a new line after finishing the iteration on the line:

```
awk '{{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i == "name:") printf $(i+1)" "$(i+2)" "} print ""; }' yourfile
```

The output:

```
1 AAA 
2 AAA 3 BBB 
1 AAA 2 BBB 5 CCC
```